# How to draw with tikz a topological continuity diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I´d like to draw with package tikz something like this:

[image]

Thanks for advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem / what do you have so far. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Note this is Q&A site, not a please do this for me service.

Answer (score 2):

There are countless examples of this type on this site. However, it is quicker for me to write a quick code than searching for them. Nonetheless I'd like to encourage you to try on your own, you'll see it's more fun. Especially since, once you are not a newcomer any more, users will be more reluctant to answer such questions for you.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[thick] 
  \node[ellipse,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4cm,label=below:$X$] (X) {};
  \node[ellipse,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=4cm,right=3cm of X,label=below:$Y$]
  (Y){};
  \node[dashed,draw] (f) at (X.center) {$f^{-1}(U)$};
  \node[circle,dashed,draw,minimum size=1cm] (U) at (Y.center) {$U$};
  \draw[-latex] (X) -- (Y) node[midway,above]{$f$};
  \draw[-latex] (U) to[bend left] (f);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]